What is the difference between $\sin(x)$ as a function and $\sin(x)$ as a trigonometric concept (ie, the ratio opposite-over-hypotenuse)?
What do we value in sine? I mean, we measure angles, but when we graph it, we use real numbers. At what point do we move from radians (a unit like ounces, liters, centimeters) to real numbers?
Now, $\sin(x)$ is a function, but what real number is $\sin(x)$? As a function, $\sin(x)$ represents the ratio of the opposite side to the hypotenuse (CO/hip). What is the difference between $\sin(x)$ as a function and $\sin(x)$ as a trigonometric concept?

Pick a prefered definition (power series, trig ratio, etc.) and you can derive all of the other properties and equivalent definitions. There is no one prefered way of defining something so ubiquitous

I think that you will find this answer relevant.
